# How to find the center of mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A massless rod of length $L$ attached to mass $m$ and with axle to cart of mass $M$. The cart has a shape of equilateral triangle (edge $L$). the cart is at rest and its center of mass is above $x=0$ and a rod is perpendicular to the ground. the cart is free to move without friction. at time t=0 the mass $m$ is released and starts to fall to the left. at time $t=\tau$ the rod is parallel to the ground. Where is the center of mass at $x$ axis at time $t=\tau$ of the cart? [image]
Why does the answer say: $mx_m+Mx_M=m(x_M-L)+Mx_M=0$? How does $x_m=x_M-L$? And isn't $x_M=mL/(M+m)$ is the center of mass of the cart with the mass $m$ and not just the cart as  the question asks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must also take the fact that while rod with mass attached falls, the triangle(with the rod ) moves to the right(conservation of momentum in x axis) As that might be a pain to calculate, consider this:

There is no force of the system of $rod + m + M$ in x direction as there is no friction. Hence, the x component of centre of mass must not change.

Comment: @ Awesome But how does $x_m=x_M-L$?

Comment: x coordinate of centre of mass of triangle is at the point where rod is attached and that of $m$ is at other end of rod. Do not forget that x=0 is where the rod $initially$ was.

Comment: Assuming that the object with mass $m$ is a point.

Comment: @Wojciech That was rather too obvious.

Comment: The whole question was rather simple, at first I wasn't sure if I understood it correctly, so You never know :)

Comment: @ Awesome how does what you have written affect the $x$ axis so that $L=x_M−x_m$? May you explain it a bit more?

Comment: @Wojciech Yeah...There's got to be something...Know that feeling :P

Comment: @user40987 Note that triangle moves to right while $m$ moves towards left. Hence $ - x_m + x_M = L$ . Assuming the rod is perfectly rigid.

Comment: @user40987 Draw a neat diagram showing both cases simultaneously and you will understand.